# Applying to transfer to a different PhD in CS program while still enrolled in a PhD program

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-assistantship, transfer-student

I am 1.5 years into my PhD in CS program. I cannot change my program to MS since I already have a masters. My research interests have been diverging from my advisor's and he told me that he might find it difficult to fund me as a research assistant from Fall 2018 onward. I still have a teaching assistantship for Spring 2018. He encouraged to look around my home CS department and also other PhD in CS programs. I am still not sure if I am even allowed to apply to PhD programs while still enrolled in one? I am just wondering if the programs I apply to will look suspiciously at my current enrollment as a PhD in CS student with 1.5 years completed. As long as I honestly explain my situation in my statements and any interviews, do I stand a chance? I would encourage commenters to tell me if they themselves have seen similar cases.

Comment: It depends. Some schools, at least in the US, will only take a certain number of coursework credits if you "transfer."

Comment: Would you have a very strong letter of recommendation from your current advisor?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am not concerned about the transfer of credits. I will gladly lose a year if it meant I can continue towards a PhD. It is my dream to be an academic. As for recommendations, I think it should be fine. I don't have stellar recommendations but I don't think anyone will write a derogatory one either!